# Best way to build my call center using Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am working on building a call center using Twilio.

Parts of problems are tackled in questions and some answers are old. Given that what I am trying to do is one of the most common usecases, I am trying to use this question to build a tutorial so that people know what is the state of the art way to build this.

Usecase detail is below:

Call Tree:

1. Customers will call the Twilio number through phone.
2. Based on phone no identification high priority customers will be sent to Agent handling flow
3. Other customers have a call tree which they have to navigate, which will support them. Some customers might end up on Agent handling flow.

Call Center: Agent handling flow is as follows:

1. Agents are handling calls using their desktop computers. They are on the support page which has a Twilio phone call widget as a pop up window.
2. All agents can handle all calls.
3. There are two types of queues. High priority and Normal.
4. All available agents ring at the same time. Anyone can pick and then other agents are moved to the next caller if available.
5. If not agent available wait for some time, including giving an IVR option for voicemail.
6. After wait timeout send to IVR.

Following is based on my understanding. Please let me know if there is a better way.

Call Tree will work as per the following tutorial: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-phone-tree/node/express

Call Center Agent handling flow will work as follows:

1. Once workspace
2. n Workers
3. 2 Task Queues - High priority and Normal
4. One Workflow which decides based on the task priority which queue to assign to.

My current queries are as follows:

1. What is the cleaned way of implementing wait for an agent for 1 minute and if agent is not available in 1 minute send to voicemail. Is this part of workflow?
2. What is the best way implement call receiving in browser. Webrtc?
3. Is there an HTML widget available for the implementing call receiving in the browser. This would include features like setting agent online/offline, receive call, end call, escalate to supervisor

Help with this will be really appreciated and will help avoid wild goose chases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andy , you should look at [Twilio taskrouter](https://www.twilio.com/taskrouter) .

[1](https://www.twilio.com/taskrouter) You can use task reservation timeout to achieve your requirement 1 . Create a task for an incoming call , taskrouter can direct the call to the matching agent and if the reservatoin timeout is set to 1 minute , the task can be redirected to either a different agent or an IVR as you require

[2](https://www.twilio.com/client) You can use [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/client) , Twilio's WebRTC . You can set incoming/outgoing capabilities as required and can easily integrate with Taskrouter to handle incoming/outgoing calls.

[3] You can build a dialler easily to implement Twilio Client , here's a tutorial to help you progress : https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript . You can find a starter up implemented in C#,Java,nodejs,php,python and ruby.

Additionally, you will find this call centre blueprint useful :) https://github.com/nash-md/twilio-contact-center  .

Comment: And now there is Twilio Studio and Twilio Flex to make it easier for you to build Contact Centre .